# External display/TV is detected but no display signal is sent to it by Macbook Pro 2020

Tags: macbook-pro, hdmi, display

I switched from Macbook Pro 2015 - with its wonderful array of ports - to the very parsimonious Macbook Pro 2020 16".  In order to drive an external LCD (53" Panasonic) I had to buy a multiport. It is a 6-way including an HDMI and a VGA.

[USB C to HDMI VGA Adapter 4K, Ifmeyasi 5 in 1 USB C Hub with HDMI, 1080P VGA, USB 3.0, USB-C PD Charging, Audio, Type C Multiport Converter Compatible with MacBook/Dell XPS/Nintendo Switch/Samsung](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07X9QFRRX)

[image]

For both the `HDMI` and the `VGA` the external display/TV is recognized.

[image]

The MBPro blinks and then the additional display is shown with the correct 1080p resolution. This is repeatable and reliable.    However *no video is being sent*.  The TV shows "PC" or "HDMI" but it remains blank.

I have used both the HDMI and VGA cable successfully from my MBPro 2015: everything is in working order.  In fact in a couple of minutes I'm going to need to switch back to it since there is a Netflix movie awaiting ..  So .. what gives with the MBPro 2020 - or the adapter maybe?

Note that I also tried plugging in the usb-c power at the same time.

I have tried both **Mirroring** and **Separate** displays.

Has anyone figured out a "winning" combination for VGA and/or HDMI using a multi-way adapter?

**Update** I just tried another multi-way adapter that I had purchased:

[image]

[UGREEN USB C Hub 4 Ports USB Type C to USB 3.0 Hub Adapter with Micro USB for MacBook Pro](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PY87TBD)

In this case I attached an additional USB-HDMI adapter into it. Also 5V power is being provided to it. The led's are lit: it's alive.  However - as with the other adapter there is nothing displayed. Lights are on (display recognized by MBPro)  but noone is home (no video).

Comment: Have you checked the display settings in system preferences?

Comment: In the question I mentioned several things related to the display settings: the second display shows up with the 1080p resolution and it is Mirrored Display by default - though I also tried Separate displays.  

Is there a particular Display setting you had in mind?

Comment: You could test using an apple tv - I use one for flexibility of connection to many different displays and projectors.

Comment: I have not used an `apple tv` - will look into that. btw I added a screenshot of the `Displays` for the `panasonic` external monitor/TV.  It behaves quite fine according to the mac. Just nothing shows up actually.  The MBPro 2015 instead drives the tv just fine

Comment: So the AppleTV is just a webapp?  If that's the case it will not help since I can't drag anything into the external display workspace.

Comment: Why do you think apple tv is “just” a web app? I use an apple rv - black box about 4” square & 1” thick... There are other things around than apps...

Comment: Well there *is* a webapp AppleTV   https://tv.apple.com/?at=1000lDR&itscg=MC_20000&itsct=atvp_brand_omd&mttnagencyid=1625&mttncc=US&mttngadurl=https%3A%2F%2Ftv.apple.com%2Fchannel%2Ftvs.sbd.4000%3F&mttngmo=&mttnmyad=444720948166&mttnmysite=uqa99n2zg0&mttnpid=305109&mttnsiteid=143238&mttnsub1=e&mttnsub2=c&mttnsub3=sidXQ476O_444720948166_uqa99n2zg0_c&mttnsubad=OUS2019801-1&mttnsubadgpname=kwd-67743848&mttnsubadgpref=75222244984&mttnsubadref=&mttnsubcmp=1746395701&mttnsubkw=apple%20tv&mttnsubpid=g&mttnsubplmnt=    But I had suspected - and correctly apparently - there were hardware like a roku

Comment: I did not say there wasn’t...

Comment: This is interesting: the Magic Touch Bar stopped working.  It was easy enough to bring back https://9to5mac.com/2020/01/20/mac-how-to-fix-and-restart-the-touch-bar/   .. but clearly MacOS is not completely happy about all that screen/display swapping

Comment: I would try hubs sold by OWC, Anker or Belkin over any other manufacturer. At our institution, we’ve found that other third party devices are either flaky or don’t work at all. Personally, I’ve found UGreen to be less than stellar, but that’s just my opinion.

Comment: @IconDaemon Thanks for the recommendation: looking now on Amazon